# Comparing the prognostic significance of a diagnosis given by doctors of differ levels of experience and different backgrounds

Tags: survival, cox-model

I am an experienced doctor but have only basic stats skills.

I have 275 doctors who evaluated 60 patients and rated each patient as having IPF (1) or not having IPF (0) (IPF = deadly pulmonary disease). I then evaluated the prognostic significance of each doctors diagnoses for the 60 patients (for this disease, death is usually considered a surrogate for accurate diagnosis).

So I have all these doctors, most of which demonstrate the ability to make prognostically significant diagnoses of IPF (using Cox regression). What I want to do is explore the doctor's demographics to make broad statements about who more likely to make a prognostically significant diagnosis...for example, doctors working in a university hospital versus community hospital, years experience, etc.

I have created a scoring system where each doctor is given a score based on experience, access to "multidisciplinary meetings," number of cases of ipf seen per month etc. The score goes from 0-8. I then created three groups

A = score 0-2
B = score 3-5
c = score 6-8

I then performed Cox regression for each doctor in each group:

GROUP A

Number of users satisfying parameters: 85
Median HR (significant): 3.3792 IQR[2.8645-4.1889]
Number significant 62/85

GROUP B

Number of users satisfying parameters: 180
Median HR (significant): 3.6232 IQR[2.9887-4.5548]
Number significant 150/180

GROUP C

Number of users satisfying parameters: 10
Median HR (significant): 4.2373 IQR[3.8302-4.5005]
Number significant 10/10

This is showing the number of doctors who had prognostically significant diagnosis and their median HR.

My questions are:

1. The HR increase and proportions of doctors with prognostic diagnoses increase from A to C. But is this a reasonable observation - only ten doctors are in group C.
2. Is there a clever way to "compare HR" from the groups that is valid, and somehow say that there is or is not a difference between the prognostic significance of the diagnoses rendered by doctors in each group? Is HR the right variable to look at?

Comment: It might be because of the hour or my complete lack of understanding in medical terminology, but can you elaborate on these: (1) Why did you perform a Cox regression? I didn't see any time dimension here. (2) What is the event - evaluating IPF positive? or correctly evaluating IPF (negative or positive)? (3) What is HR? (4) Why coalesce disparate attributes into a single measure, and why break it down into 0-2, 3-5 and 6-8?